# How to add functionality for uploading PDF files?

Tags: php

I'm creating a form where user can insert an image in jpg, jpeg, png, gif format. The idea is to add also pdf files besides images, but I cannot figure how to add that functionality. I'm sorry for asking something that is already explained many times but I'm stuck on this for a while, and I tried to change code in many ways but still nothing.

This is the code I have in user.php

```
function uploadFile() {


    $result_message = "";

    if($this->image) {

      $target_directory = "uploads/";
      $target_file = $target_directory . $this->image;
      $file_type = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

      $file_upload_error_messages = "";

      $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
      if($check != false) {
        // submited file is an image
      } else {
        $file_upload_error_messages .= "<div>Submitted file is not an image.</div>";
      }

      $allowed_file_types = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "pdf");
      if(!in_array($file_type, $allowed_file_types)) {
        $file_upload_error_messages .= "<div>Only JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, PDF are allowed.</div>";
      }

      if(file_exists($target_file)) {
        $file_upload_error_messages .= "<div>Image already exists. Try to change file name.</div>";
      }

      if($_FILES['image']['size'] > (1024000)) {
        $file_upload_error_messages .= "<div>Image must ber less than 1 MB in size.</div>";
      }

      if(!is_dir($target_directory)) {
        mkdir($target_directory, 0777, true);
      }
      if(empty($file_upload_error_messages)) {
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {

        } else {
          $result_message .= "<div class='alert alert-danger'>";
            $result_message .= "<div>Unable to upload photo.</div>";
            $result_message .= "<div>Update the record to upload photo.</div>";
          $result_message .= "</div>";
        }
      }
      else {
        $result_message .= "<div class='alert alert-danger'>";
          $result_message .= "{$file_upload_error_messages}";
          $result_message .= "<div>Update the record to upload photo.</div>";
        $result_message .= "</div>";
      }
    }
    return $result_message;
  }
```

and this is the code I have in register.php

```
       $image = !empty($_FILES["image"]["name"]) ? sha1_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) . "-" . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]) : "";
```

When I try to change or to add some new feature for pdf files I get an error that says undefined index...

This is what I also have tried but without success

```
$targetfolder = "testupload/";

 $targetfolder = $targetfolder . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']) ;

 $ok=1;

$file_type=$_FILES['file']['type'];

if ($file_type=="application/pdf" || $file_type=="image/gif" || $file_type=="image/jpeg") {

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetfolder))

 {

 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['file']['name']). " is uploaded";

 }

 else {

 echo "Problem uploading file";

 }

}

else {

 echo "You may only upload PDFs, JPEGs or GIF files.<br>";

}
```

Comment: Can you post a full error message so we can see where you got that undefined index error? I could suggest that if you handle file upload in one file, the other one cannot access the file through $_FILES. That's a possible reason why you get this error. Please provide more information on what's the action of your upload form.

Comment: I tried for example for replace image in $_FILES with file,and I'm not getting an error but when I check database  row for files, it's empty. Then I tried to add  with uploading pictures, files also and then I have an error that says undefined index

Comment: I am sure that It's not saying only undefined index, but also in which file and on what line it happened. Can you share a full error?

Comment: You can see code I've added in question, and that' something I've also tried but without any luck

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\MAMP\htdocs\php-login-script-level-1\objects\user.php on line 140

Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\MAMP\htdocs\php-login-script-level-1\objects\user.php on line 142

Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\MAMP\htdocs\php-login-script-level-1\objects\user.php on line 143
Invalid file ...this is the error message I get @RenéBeneš

Comment: The error means that there is no uploaded file with name "file". What is the name attribute of the upload input in your form? It must match the name of the field in $_FILES. If your name attribute is "image" you refer to it as $_FILES["image"]

Comment: It's image! So I assume that I need to change it into file instead of image